# Java8 Groupby on a field & collect object

Tags: java, group-by, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a list of the following sort:

```
List<Employee> employees = ....
```

where

```
class Employee{
    private String employeeId;
    private String employeeName;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(employeeId, employee.employeeId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(employeeId);
    }
}
```

The following code gives me each Employee Name and its frequency:

```
Map<String,Long> employeeNameWithFreq = employees
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Employee::getEmployeeName,
                Collectors.counting()));
```

How to `groupBy` in Java8 streams on the field `employeeName` field and get the corresponding `Employee` object as the key in the output map & freq as it's value? I mean output should be of the sorts of `Map<Employee,Long>`

**Note:** The `equals()` & `hashcode()` methods are already overridden for field `employeeId`, so can't use them. Basically looking for a solution where comparing field can be passed as an argument.

Comment: Why don't you want to override equals/hashcode?

Comment: The grouping criteria could be on a field other than what uniquely identifies it.

Comment: Well if you don't find anything from the ready made collectors, a custom collector can always be written. The `groupingBy` collector can be used as an example. Of course then the `Employee` key will be only one of the potential matches, so make sure your code doesn't make any assumptions on that.

Comment: @All updated the question with reason to not use `equals()` & `hashcode()` method approach

Comment: What's the use of the `Employee` key anyway? If you're grouping by, let's say first name and then you see that there's `5` employees named `John`. Then you have some random `John` as the key....what's the use?

Comment: Right, maybe the name as key and list of employees with said name as value would be more appropriate?

Comment: `Employee` is just an example. The grouping could be applied for some other types of classes also.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you'll end up with a random representative as the key. Is that something you want, and if it is, why?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that that is the real goal, but based on your question it looks like you might want to use `TreeMap` with custom `Comparator` which will compare Employee objects only by some selected fields (like here `name`).

Demo

```
TreeMap<Employee, Long> map = Stream.
        of( new Employee(1, "Adam"),
            new Employee(2, "Thomas"),
            new Employee(3, "Adam")
        ).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(),
                () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName)),
                Collectors.counting())
        );

System.out.println(map.get(new Employee(33, "Adam"))); // Output: 2
//  ID will be ignored by Comparator ---^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply stream over the `Employee`s a second time?

```
Map<String,Long> employeeNameWithFreq = employees
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Employee::getEmployeeName,
            Collectors.counting()
        )
    );

Map<Employee, Long> employeeToNumColleaguesWithSameName = employees.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            employee -> employeeNameWithFreq.get(employee.getEmployeeName())
        )
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use Employee object as Key of the result map since even if they share the same name they are different identities! If you like to have a map that contains the count of the occurrences of a particular name then you should either use the Name as key and put list of employees as value, so this way you could access the size of the list as well as each of the Employees who shares this particular name.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> employeeIdWithFreq = employees
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors
                .groupingBy(Employee::getEmployeeName, Collectors.toList()));
```

And then you have the name (the only property that those objects share!) as a key and ***employeeIdWithFreq.get("name").size()*** as count of occurances. If you are interested of the presence of any of the Employees you could easily access it via ***employeeIdWithFreq.get(employee.getName())***

You could achieve what you've asked but this way the Key could be any of the matching Employee objects....

```
Map<Employee, Integer> employeeIdWithFreq = employees
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmployeeName, Collectors.toList()))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(list-> list.stream().findAny(), List::size));
```

Comment: This was suggested, but this doesn't allow you to do the grouping by a custom field.

Comment: You can't group by name but put the first person who has the name as key for the count of all users sharing the name.

Comment: What? Your answer doesn't fulfill the requirements.

Comment: Kayaman there is no such answer which fits the requirement and doesn't violate data integrity ;)

Comment: "*You can't group by name but put the first person who has the name as key for the count of all users sharing the name*" that is true for HashMap, but TreeMap can use Comparator which may use only fields we want (name) which will ignore others (id) (unless I am mistaken, in which case I will be very grateful for any corrections).

Comment: I'm not saying it's technically impossible but what am I saying is that it should not be done in this manner since this sounds quite tricky and catchy ;) Also it could be achieved with any implementation of map. Updating my answer if that's what you want ;) Just the object used as key will be any of the matches and there will be no arbitrary choosing for it...

Comment: I have upvoted for the last edit, that is what the OP is currently asking for. The problem was what employee to select once we have grouped by name.

Comment: @marsouf The OP still hasn't addressed the issue of the key being randomly chosen from the matches. The problem still exists.

Comment: Your edit creates `Map<Optional<Employee>, Integer>` not `Map<Employee, Integer>` but that can be easily fixed with `list.stream().findAny().get()`. Problem is that it still places some (even randomly selected) Employee and will return HashMap, but since Employee overrides equals/hashcode methods to use only ID we will not be able to get `value` using as key Employee with same name but *different ID* because HashMap uses only equals and hashcode to compare keys.

Comment: The implementation you've suggested Stores the first object that has no match according to your custom comparator and bounds as value the count of total occurrences matched by the comparator compared to this very first(key) object. When the get method of the result map is invoked it uses this very same comparator to return the occurrences of Employee objects matching this criteria (name in our case). Result map is unusable in the case when you have newcomers that need to be added and evaluated as equals.

Comment: The difference between your solution and mine is that your map uses Name to sort out the objects and it will return a value if the get is involved with an object sharing the same property value for "Name" field... Behavior of having Map<String,Long> will be exactly the same. Either you admit it or not you are having a key of type Employee that is held only for the use of a single field of its own -> String (name). It is true that comparator could be customized even more so it take into account more than one criteria but still the author of this question needs to realize what's the issue here.